# Overflow on nested element without predefined height

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am building a grid component and trying to get the body to trigger a scrollbar when the content exceeds the viewport of the outer element. Unfortunately, I am only getting this working when applying a height on the .body element. I would like to avoid this as it would require me to runtime apply a height via scripting, as well as having to keep track of any changes on the elements that affect its height.

Is there something I could explore, purely CSS wise to get this done? Note that the scrollbar visible in the snippet is based on the snippet contents overflowing, not on the body element overflowing.

```css
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

.grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.headerwrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bodywrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.body {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /*height:300px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="headerwrap">
      <div class="header">
        <table border="1" style="width:2000px;">
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
            <td>f</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bodywrap">
      <div class="body">
        <table border="1" style="width:2000px;height:1000px">
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the solution; had to use flex box and with that it becomes a bit limited as I have to set fixed header heights. But this is already miles better than having to script everything together.

```js
function Throttle(ms, callback) {
    let lastCall = 0;
    return function () {
        let now = new Date().getTime(),
            diff = now - lastCall;
        if (diff >= ms) {
            lastCall = now;
            callback.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}

function Grid(){
    this.head = document.querySelector('.head');
    this.body = document.querySelector('.body');
    this.frozenBody = document.querySelector('.bodywrap>.frozen');
    
    this.body.addEventListener('scroll', Throttle(5, this.Scroll.bind(this)));
}
Grid.prototype = {
    Scroll : function(){
        let scrollLeft = event.srcElement.scrollLeft;
        let scrollTop = event.srcElement.scrollTop;

        this.head.style.transform = `translateX(-${scrollLeft}px)`;
        this.frozenBody.style.transform = `translateY(-${scrollTop}px)`;
    }
}
new Grid();
```

```css
html,margin{
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}
.outer{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:500px;
}
.grid{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;  
}
.headwrap{
    display:flex;
    flex:0 0 75px;
    flex-direction:row;     
    margin-right:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:blue;
}   
    .headwrap .frozen{
        flex:0 0 50px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background:lime;
        z-index:1;
        
    }
    .head{
        flex:1 1 auto;
        overflow:hidden;
        z-index:0;
    }
.bodywrap{
    display:flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
    flex-direction:row;         
    overflow:auto;
    
}
    .bodywrap .frozen{
        flex:0 0 50px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        background:lime;
        z-index:1;
    }
    .body{
        flex:1 1 auto;
        overflow:auto;
        background:silver;
        z-index:0;
    }
td{
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="headwrap">
            <div class="frozen">
                <table border="1" style="height:75px">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:50">1</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="head">
                <table border="1" style="width:2000px;height:75px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>                  
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bodywrap">
            <div class="frozen">
                <table border="1" style="width:50px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <table border="1" style="width:2000px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow: scroll;` on the `outer` to allow scrolling when the content exceeds the viewport of the `y-axis`. This enables scrolling on the `x-axis` also when the content exceeds the horizontal viewport.

When using `tables` I like to add a manual scrollbar using `body::-webkit-scrollbar`. See the `~Snippet 2` for a demonstration.

```css
.outer {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 500px;
}

.grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.headerwrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bodywrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.body {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /*height:300px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="headerwrap">
      <div class="header">
        <table border="1" style="width:2000px;">
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
            <td>f</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bodywrap">
      <div class="body">
        <table border="1" style="width:2000px;height:1000px">
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit ~** Snippet 2

```css
.outer {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.headerwrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.bodywrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  /*height:300px;*/
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
 
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="headerwrap">
      <div class="header">
        <table border="1" style="width:2000px;">
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
            <td>f</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bodywrap">
      <div class="body">
        <table border="1" style="width:2000px;height:1000px">
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Outer should always have an overflow:hidden, e.g. the header and the body can exceed the width of this element. If that happens, the body will provide scrollbars and the header will be synchronized via script.

Also visibile in your snippet. You now end up with double scrollbars, and still have to scroll to reach the bottom horizontal scrollbar of the body element.

So appreciate the effort, but this isn't it :)

Comment: @MichaSchopman should include more details, such as markup image with desired result in the question.

Comment: The use case is quite simple. I want to have a body element, that shows scrollbars without having to enforce a fixed height on the element. It shows a scrollbar when it's contents exceed the parent viewport.

Comment: @MichaSchopman Simple then. See `snippet 2` & resize the browser vertically. As soon as there is the slightest bit of overflow, `scrollbar` appears.

Comment: @MichaSchopman let me know if you have any questions or if this is not the result you were after.